# Bootstrap in SPA - a good idea?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, performance, single-page-application

What do you think about using bootstrap in SPAs instead of writing your own styles? As everybody knows - bootstrap isn't lightweight and it slows down static sites. But in SPA we don't change the pages, so I guess once we load bootstrap, it won't have negative impact on performance of our app. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. And it will be ok. And there are several reasons for that:

1. this is true

   > in SPA we don't change the pages, so I guess once we load bootstrap
2. you can use popular CDN - and this will reduce the render latency
3. you can use webpack or babel to compile css and remove unused styles
4. you cam manually customize it and remove all you do not need